# Convergents as solution to $x^2 - dy^2=m, m \leq \sqrt d$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Let $d$ and $m$ be positive integers such that $d$ is not a square and such that $m\leq\sqrt{d}$. I want to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are positive integers satisfying $x^2-dy^2=m$, then $x/y$ is a convergent of $\sqrt d$.

Any hints how I can prove such statement? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Theorem 7.24 in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.

You asked for hints, so read just enough of the proof so that you can finish it yourself.  If you do not already have [Theorem (3)](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/converge.html), which is needed to complete the proof, you can do the same at the referenced document.

Rearranging the equation, we have
$$\frac{x}{y} - \sqrt d = \frac{m}{y(x + y\sqrt d)},$$
and hence
$$0 < \frac{x}{y} - \sqrt d \le \frac{\sqrt d}{y(x + y\sqrt d)} = \frac{1}{y^2(x/(y\sqrt d) + 1)}.$$

Also, $0 < x/y - \sqrt d$ implies $x/(y\sqrt d) > 1$, and therefore
$$\frac{x}{y} - \sqrt d < \frac{1}{y^2(1 + 1)} = \frac{1}{2y^2}.$$
By [Theorem (3)](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/converge.html), $x/y$ is a convergent of $\sqrt d$.